# Extending Kafka's Retention Policy

Tags: apache-kafka

There are two out of the box retention policies (message deletion strategy) for topics; delete and compact.
Former will delete messages based on log file size or date, latter will delete duplicate messages periodically by using message key. I'm wondering if there was a mechanism to extend Kafka's Log Compaction functionality? for example cleaning messages by an expiration date or other custom criteria?

Answer (score 1):

you can use broker configs such as:

`log.retention.bytes`
The maximum size of the log before deleting it.

`log.retention.hours`

The number of hours to keep a log file before deleting it (in hours), tertiary to log.retention.ms property.

`log.retention.minutes`

The number of minutes to keep a log file before deleting it (in minutes), secondary to log.retention.ms property. If not set, the value in log.retention.hours is used.

`log.retention.ms`

The number of milliseconds to keep a log file before deleting it (in milliseconds), If not set, the value in log.retention.minutes is used.

Comment: These configurations are all related to existing retention policies, My question is about how to **extend** these retention policies, like adding a new retention policy called "expire" so that cleaner thread would delete messages by their expiration date.

Comment: As far as I know about kafka I don't thats possible.
Doing that would require modifying the broker source code.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to suggest this in Kafka KIP. I know that ActiveMQ has such a feature.

Comment: I think that wouldn't be a good option as Kafka is used to handle an infinite stream of data. If you specify a particular expiration date then there will be no expiration info for the stream of data coming after that.